# How to Snow pipe job programmatically?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Instead on using Snowpipe, I want to do  build snowpipe programmatically.

i) Snowpipe automatically checks for files and loads into staging area. I am using  Copy Command to copy json file s3 bucket and load into staging area .

ii) Snowpipe also checks if a file is updated or new file has arrived in S3. How would I do this in python?

iii) Snowpipe also avoids de-duplication. How to achieve the same

Do I. need to check S3 bucket last edited time and then load it into staging Snowflake?

Regards,

Yu

Answer (score 0):

We built a data pipeline prior to Snowpipe existing, thing to note:

The `COPY` command will not load the same file, (within a week window), but each time to run the command it does pull the full object list of the prefix given.

The latter part is takes time, thus the recommendation to load data into `year/month/day` paths, depending on your data file rates.

In our loader we keep a high watermark of the date of the last date of the data loaded, so if in was within the hour we give `data_type/year/month/day/hour` prefixes, but if it was a month ago we would use `data_type/year/prior-month/last-day` and do day sized chunks loads until we where in the same hour.

We also knew the above would avoid loading the same file twice (originally the loaded files list was forever, but the rather quickly swapped to a weeks of history). Any ways, we had data streams that where not 100% guaranteed duplication free, so how whole pipeline had de-duplication baked in, so we could handle upstream error, or force the reloading of the same files if we had a SQL mistake.

We tended to load data into a "landing table" that did deduplication of the load batch data, then transform the data into the shapes we wanted on the history tables, and then transform it again into the form we want for reading optimizations. So time was deduplicated in the load "real time stream" and others, if the data was outside a window would be done as a once a night be reprocess, this meant the deduplication of non-critical high volume data flows, where updated with very small transitory accuracy (our prior system used to take 12+ hours to process some data so all critical reports already where staggered), anyways the point is having deduplication built it, can be rather helpful. but the costs need to be managed.

point ii) you can use S3 event for when file land, to trigger you code/lambda, or as we did we ether knew we had just caused the file to be written, so knew to read them. Or processed in a loop (that would not re-run in the same minute to avoid pointless spinning in quite times).

Our data arrival curve had very strong day/high volume times, and night/low volumes times, so we programmatically increased the warehouse max cluster size in the day, to keeps loop times lower, and then at the night, shrunk the cluster size down, which saved credits that we then ran the "more expensive deduplications on a much larger warehouse at midnight" thus moving the credit spend to a small duration window later.

It's all not to hard to do, and it you have infrastructure to run the coordinating Python/JavaScript, a very hand solution, you can see all your errors, you can pause tasks to do upgrades, to can add support for dependences/conflicts/blocks/order between tasks and thus not waste CPU time while tables are locks by other SQL.